# Strange behavior of add_property in Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, boost-python

I met a strange behavior when using `add_property` of Boost.Python.

Here is the example codes, it simply add two properties (read-only & read-write) to the wrapped class.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

struct X {
    X( int value ) : val( value ) {}

    int get_value() const
    { return val; }

    void set_value(int value)
    { val = value; }

    int val;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello) {
    class_<X>("X", init<int>() )
        // NOTE the order
        .add_property( "val_r", &X::get_value )  // read-only first
        .add_property( "val_rw", &X::get_value, &X::set_value ) // read-write second
    ;
}
```

and the build command:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -shared -L/usr/local/lib -o bp.dll bp.cpp -lboost_python -lpython2.7
```

I'm working in Cygwin x86_64, so the file extension is `.dll`. As for Ubuntu just change the output extension to `.so`.

When importing the `bp` module, it crashes with a *Segmentation fault*. The core dump file doesn't contain any call stack information.

However, if I change the order of `add_property` (as below) to add the read-write property first, it works ok.

```
.add_property( "val_rw", &X::get_value, &X::set_value ) // read-write first
.add_property( "val_r", &X::get_value )  // read-only second
```

My environment:

- Cygwin x86_64
- python 2.7.10
- gcc 5.4.0
- boost: 1.60.0

BTW, there's no problem in Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) whatever the `add_property` order is.

Why would this happen?

Comment: I'm not seeing it. Perhaps conflicting versions of libraries/compiler flags

Comment: Were you using Cygwin? @sehe

Comment: I was using the browser.